# Como alterar uma virgula, por um ponto, num numero decimal no interior de uma string

Tags: php, mysql

Estava a tentar fazer o seguinte:

String: `ajskjnsjs, eeiisois, 10,98 oismsnsjh;`

Neste caso pretendia alterar apenas **a virgula** do número por um **ponto** ficando o resto da `string` igual.   Estava a usar o comando `regexp_replace` do MySQL.

Alguém tem ideia de uma solução?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### PHP:

Utilize o *REGEX*:

```
/(?<=\d),+(?=\d)/
```

Utilize a função `preg_replace` do PHP:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\d),+(?=\d)/', '.', $string);
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f80713c4452dd918cad42f915f76952b13d6e5a4)

---

### MariaDB:

> Exige suporte para `?`.

Utilize o *REGEX*:

```
(?<=[0-9]),+(?=[0-9])
```

Utilize a função `regexp_replace` no MariaDB:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(coluna, '(?<=[0-9]),+(?=[0-9])', '.')
```

---

### Alternativa sem `?`:

Utilize o *REGEX*:

```
([0-9]),([0-9])
```

Utilize a função `regexp_replace` no MariaDB (talvez MySQL ([UDF](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp))):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(coluna, '([0-9]),([0-9])', '\\1.\\2')
```

Comment: versão **PHP** 100% funcional. Na versão **MySQL** obetenho o seguinte erro : #1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp.

Comment: @RedFenix adicionei uma outra opção, sem uso do `?`. Não tenho MySQL, apenas MariaDB, fica inviável testar.

Comment: 100% working Obrigado